# Android - Request accessibility permission on Xiaomi

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, xiaomi, miui

what is the proper way to request accessibility permission on xiaomi/miui devices programmatically?

The code snippet below on all other devices takes you to the screen with the option to enable accessibility. But on Xiaomi devices it takes to a screen with the following options: "Volume Shortcut", "Accessibility Menu" and "Downloaded Services", and none of these options enable the accessibility system.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Thaks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had same problem but when you  click on 'download service' you can get to see all apps asking for accessibility permission.